# Vue Test Utils (Mocha, Chai) - how to wait for http request

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, mocha.js, vue-component

I need to write a unit test for Single File Component in Vue JS. My project is based on [Vue Cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) and for testing I chose Mocha/Chai combination.

My component uses Axios to load some JSON from URL before it is mounted. At this stage, I **do not want to mock** this load during testing, I just want this request to fail and then display some information.

**Very** simplified example of my component Async.vue:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Async Request test</h1>
    <b v-if="finished">Request finished</b>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import axios from "axios";

@Component
export default class AsyncRequest extends Vue {
finished = false;
beforeMount() {
    axios.get("not/real/url").then((response) => {
      this.finished = true;
    },
    (error) => {
      this.finished = true;
    });
  }
}
</script>`
```

And this is my testing script:

```js
import { expect } from "chai";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Async from "@/components/Async.vue";

describe("Async.vue", () => {
  it("Renders 'Request finished'", (done) => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Async, {});
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.text()).to.include("test"); // it passes
      expect(wrapper.text()).to.include("finished"); // it fails
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

I would expect my test to pass.
I just need to test my component after beforeMount is finished.
Let me stress again - I do not want to get real or mocked data from axios.get for now.

Comment: You still need to mock the `GET` request. You just need to mock a failure rather than a success.

Comment: I have installed https://github.com/axios/moxios/ and mocked the request. Good news: mocking is working, as my component gets the data returned by moxios.
Bad news: test is still failing, as `wrapper.text()` is apparently tested before request is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Stephen Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1403714/stephen-thomas) comment, I was directed to the right path.

Two conditions must be met:

1. Request must be mocked (I have used https://github.com/axios/moxios/).
2. [Flush-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises) must be used.

See improved testing code bellow:

```js
import moxios from "moxios";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import flushPromises from "flush-promises";
import Async from "@/components/Async.vue";

describe("Async.vue", () => {
  it("Renders 'Request finished'", async () => {
    moxios.install();
    moxios.stubRequest(/.*/, {
      status: 200,
      responseText: "hello guy",
    });

    const wrapper = shallowMount(Async, {});
    await flushPromises();

    expect(wrapper.text()).to.include("finished"); // it passes now
  });
});
```

Comment: Why does the request be mocked?